# How can I implement the "Clean Up Unused Data Blocks" menu item in Python so I can add it to my addon's panel?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on, customization

My question is basically the title. I have a custom sandbox add-on that I'm working on as I learn more about Python scripting. I use it to make my commonly used functions easier to use.

This is the feature I want to implement:

[image: Automate Clean Up]

I've tried switching to the scripting tab and then seeing what gets output in the mini terminal when I run the clean up, but it spits out nothing useful.

I could really use some help here and it would be hugely appreciated!

If it helps I could also upload my source code.

Comment: Turn on developer extras, python tooltips etc  in preferences > interface, then use the operator displayed.

Comment: Thank you! Enabling tool-tips was it.

Comment: NP. As you can imagine same question gets asked alot, generally a different op on a different menu, but ultimately same question... and very very hard to find via a search, without knowing the answer.   Might look into adding a wiki question re issues like this, "Tips for staring in `bpy`" .. viewing UI source,  using the python console autocomplete, etc,